# Get total number of results or percentage above threshold with promql

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I am trying to get a percentage based on a threshold. My data looks like the following:

```
{
  "request": {
    "url": "api/datasources/proxy/1/api/v1/query_range?query=health&start=1635183780&end=1635184080&step=15",
    "method": "GET",
    "hideFromInspector": false
  },
  "response": {
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
      "resultType": "matrix",
      "result": [
        {
          "metric": {
            "__name__": "health",
            "application": "myapp"
          },
          "values": [
            [
              1635183780,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183795,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183810,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183825,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183840,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183855,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183870,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183885,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183900,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183915,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183930,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183945,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183960,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183975,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635183990,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635184005,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635184020,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635184035,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635184050,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635184065,
              "3"
            ],
            [
              1635184080,
              "3"
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the percentage of when the value was 3. So like in this case it is 100%, but if it goes below 3, that would drop the percentage down.

I am using promql in grafana. I have tried to do something like `count` or `count_over_time`, but getting an error since the result says it is an instant vector and not range. My understanding is pretty limited, so I'm not sure how to get the total number of values represented here. to even do something like `count(health == 3) / count(health)`

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. I was able to use count(metric==3)/count(metric) without problems. Could you clarify what is exactly the error?

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira I get the error when using over time, but when using count, I only get 1. I want to get the number of results, which would be 21 in this case.

Comment: count(health==3) will return 21, but in your question, you have said "I want to get the percentage of when the value was 3" and that you got an error trying that.

Comment: Yes, i get an error when using count_over_time. count works, but i am not getting 21, i only get 1.  I do want a percentage, but i included that in case there was another way to get the same result (something built-in to promql)

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to figure this out in case anyone has issues.

In grafana, I had to change the type to instant. This will query the api using a query call instead of query_range.

Then you can use count_over_time: `count_over_time(health[15m])`

I still needed to get this metric where the value is 3, and simply doing `count_over_time((health == 3)[15m])` does not work. It's basically missing one thing and that is the step. So, my final query is ended up being: `count_over_time((health == 3)[15m:])` and this got me the result I needed.

Comment: It is better explicitly setting the `step` duration after the colon in square brackets, otherwise only a part of raw samples may be taken into account if the `step` query arg passed to `/api/v1/query_range` exceeds the interval between raw samples. On the other hand, if the `step` in query arg is smaller than the interval between samples, then the query will return inflated results. It is better to use [count_eq_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_eq_over_time) function from MetricsQL instead.

Comment: @valyala Is metricsQL a plugin? Still trying to get used to grafana and how it works.

Comment: MetricsQL is query language for VictoriaMetrics. It is inspired by PromQL and it is mostly backwards-compatible with PromQL (there are a few exceptions mentioned at https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html ). This means that Prometheus dashboards in Grafana should continue working after switching from Prometheus to VictoriaMetrics